# Solution to the wave equation PDEs multivariable calculus /chain rule question

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, wave-equation, chain-rule

I've spent the last day trying to work out a solution for this question:

If u = f(x+ct) + g(x-ct) where f,g are twice-differentiable functions of 1 variable and c is a constant, show that $\partial^2 u / \partial t^2$ = $c^2 \partial ^2u / \partial x^2$

I end up getting: 
$\partial^2 u / \partial t^2$ = $c^2 (\partial ^2u / \partial g^2)(g'(x-ct))^2 -2c^2(\partial ^2u/\partial g \partial f) * f'(x+ct)*g'(x-ct) + c^2(\partial ^2u/\partial f^2)*(f'(x+ct))^2 $

and

$c^2\partial ^2u/\partial x^2 = c^2(\partial ^2u/\partial g^2)*(g'(x-ct))^2 +  2c^2(\partial ^2u/\partial g \partial f)*(f'(x+ct))*(g'(x-ct)) + c^2(\partial ^2u/\partial f^2)*(f'(x+ct))^2 $

the minus term in Utt seems to prevent the two sides from cancelling out. Only way I can see it working is if $\partial ^2u/\partial g \partial f = 0 $.

Anyone have any ideas where I went wrong?

Thanks

Comment: your inconventioal way to differentiate function is actually correct. Since $u = f + g$, u is linear in f and g, that $\frac{\partial u}{\partial f} = 1$ and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial g} = 1$ , $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial f \partial g} = 0$, $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial f^2} = 0$, $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial g^2} = 0$ . But no one does this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your differentiaon is not correct in convetional way.

Let $u(x, t) = f(x + c t) + g(x -ct)$, then
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = f'(x +ct) + g'(x -ct)$$
$$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} = f''(x +ct) + g''(x - ct)$$
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = cf'(x +ct) - c g'(x - ct)$$
$$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2} = c^2f''(x +ct) + c^2 g''(x - ct) = c^2 \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}$$

Comment: Oh. So basically I interpreted it as f(x+ct,x-ct) or say f(u,v) instead of f(u) and f(v) ?

Comment: u interpreted as u = u(f, g) = u(f(x +ct), g(x-ct)), which is inconventiional but correct in math anyway. We just consider  u = f (x +ct) + g(x -ct) directly.

Comment: Yeah awesome, that makes sense. Thanks so much. I can't upvote you because I dont have enough rep but this is the best answer